# Scaffold model without additional gem in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am just looking into Sinatra and trying to figure out is there a way to scaffold models just like in Rails we use `rails g model Name`. I came across few gems but isn't there anything in-built in Sinatra that allows to do so. I would just like to run a cmnd and the model, migration and the schema for that model to generate automatically.

Comment: Nope. Sinatra supports a external views, but scaffolding and an ORM are not built in.

Comment: I would use [sinatra-activerecord](https://github.com/sinatra-activerecord/sinatra-activerecord), it will get you pretty close to rails.